# Strange behavior of Python 'is'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python version: Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32.

```
>>> 256 is (2**8)
True
>>> 512 is (2**9)
False
```

**UPD**

```
>>> print(id(256), id(2**8))
1933723392 1933723392
>>> print(id(512), id(2**9))
60976880 60976704
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is` checks to see if two variables are stored *at the same memory location*.  The following states that the two numbers are stored at different locations in memory:

```
>>> 512 is (2**9)
False
```

Very likely, what you really wanted to know was if the numbers were *equal*.  To do that, test for equality:

```
>>> 512 == (2**9)
True
```

#### Exceptional case: `None`

`None` does not have any sensible value.  Consequently, checking if something is *equal* to `None` is generally not useful.  To find out if some variable is `None`, use `is`:

```
>>> x = None
>>> x is None
True
```

Comment: `==` can be thought of as "value equality", that is, if two things look
the same, `==` should return `True`. `is` can be thought of as `object identity`, that is, the two things actually are the same object. `object identity` normally translates as having the same memory address.